# How can I change the default search box to use another browser?

Tags: browser

I've installed Dolphin which I love, but the search box on the homepage always defaults to the regular browser.  I'd prefer it just go into Dolphin right away..how can I do this?

Comment: I had the same issue, it also meant that other apps such as Twitter, Facebook etc would launch the stock Browser app instead of Dolphin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In settings, goto applications > internet > clear defaults. Next time you perform a search it should ask you which you would like to use and simply select dolphin.

Comment: Internet doesn't show up, I tried Browser, but defaults is grayed out

Comment: It should give you the option to clear defaults under Browser. If its greyed out try doing the same for Google Search.